# echo woocommerce stock quantity of a particular product id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

As the title says, how do i echo the stock quantity of a particular product id? Let's say the product id is "1100" and i want the stock quantity to appear in a page that is not part of the product archive. Is that possible?

For example, in an empty page, it should appear as

"Product A leftover stock: 10"

I am just learning to code and have come up with the following, but no result appear:

```
function nntest(){
    global $woocommerce;
    global $product;
    $product_id = 1100;
    echo $product->get_stock_quantity();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use get_post_meta() function to get values from database.

this values are stored in wp_postmeta table.

```
$stock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_stock', true );
```

Comment: So, how to read the stock values of variable products of a product?

Comment: Hey @Digerkam, did you ever get the total number of _stock for variable products by any chance?

Answer (score 11):

Another option if you want to work with the actual WC_Product class:

```
$product_id = 1100;
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);
echo $product->get_stock_quantity();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether the product is in stock or out of stock use:

```
$stock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_stock_status', true );
```

It would either return 'instock' or 'outofstock' depending on the stock status.

If you have enabled the option "Enable stock management at product level" and you want stock quantity, use:

```
$stock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_stock', true );
```